# Protect zip file from multiple unzipping

Tags: unzip

Suppose my customers are offline customers (Don't have Internet connection). So I want my employees to install the software. My application runs in linux server and I have a script that install the required software and my application into the system.
Biggest problem is that my employees can steal the software and sell it to other customers.
I was thinking some security mechanism to protect from stealing the software.

1. The entire script can not be copied from the Pen drive into the server
2. I shall zip and make my scripts and installers password protected and the password will expire after unzipping the folder into the pen drive.

The problem is I was didn't get any suitable example/tool in google to expire my zip file exactly after one use in Ubuntu/Linux. Almost whole day i have done my research on this but didnt get any clue on this.

Can someone help me out if you have prior experience on this or any better idea is appreciated.
Please note: I know that if someone is trying to steal/break my software means it is a good software blah blah blah...... idea. So any opinion or direction is much appreciated

Comment: It is not possible to protect any program. You can just make it harder. Use some registration key based on computer hardware identification. There is no such thing in zip.

Comment: Wait, you're running a business where you can't trust your own employees?